# Showing a particular part of toy contour tends to 0?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin{x}}{x^2 + a^2}dx$$

I translate it to its complex equivalent:

$$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^{R}\frac{z\sin{z}}{z^2 + a^2}dz = \int_{C}\frac{z\sin{z}}{z^2 + a^2}dz - \int_{\gamma}\frac{z\sin{z}}{z^2 + a^2}dz$$

where $C$ is a half circle with radius $R$, above the real axis, and $\gamma$ is only the curved (top part) of the half circle.

I am trying to show that $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z\sin{z}}{z^2 + a^2}dz$$ tends to 0 as $R \rightarrow \infty$.

I have that:

$$\left| \int_{\gamma}\frac{z\sin{z}}{z^2 + a^2}dz \right|\leq \pi R \cdot \sup_{\xi \in \gamma} \mid \frac{z\sin{z}}{z^2 + a^2} \mid$$

That is, the integral is upper bounded by the length of the contour multiplied by the supremium of the contour.

This leads me to:

$$\pi R \cdot \sup_{\xi \in \gamma} \left| \frac{z\sin{z}}{z^2 + a^2} \right| \leq \pi R \cdot \mid \frac{R}{R^2 + a^2} \mid$$

as $\sin{z}$ has a maximum of 1. But what other inequalities can I produce to show that this tends to 0 as $R \rightarrow \infty$?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to see this approached via the integrand $\dfrac{z \sin z}{z^2+a^2}$. I'd have expected $\dfrac{z e^{i z}}{z^2+a^2}$, with the desired integral showing up as the imaginary part of the integral along the real line.

Comment: I'm new to contour integration, and am not quite familiar with what you're talking about -- I've typically only taken a real-valued integration and translated it to its complex equivalent. I've then expressed it as a sum of integrals via Cauchy's Theorem, and just used the integral (out of the sum of integrals) that corresponds to the original integral (for instance, for $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}$, I would choose $\int_{-R}^{R}$. Can you give me an example of the desired integral showing up as the imaginary part of the integral along the real line?

Comment: Following up on Semiclassical's comment, for general $R$, you don't necessarily have that $\lvert \sin(z) \rvert$ is bounded by 1. For instance, $\sin(i) = i \sinh(1)$, and $\sinh(1) > 1$.